# proof of harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

$s_{2^k}= 1+ \sum_{j=1}^{k}(\sum_{m=2^{k-1}+1}^{2^k} \frac 1m)$
How is this true? For example, when $2^k = 4$, $s_4 = 1+(1/3 +1/4)+(1/3+1/4)$, which is wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a typo the 2nd time $s_{2^k}$ is written, compare to the first one (which is the right one).

Comment: ah, okay. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously confusing.$$s_{2^k}= 1+ \sum_{j=1}^{k}(\sum_{m=2^{k-1}+1}^{2^k} \frac 1m)$$

It should have been $$s_{2^k}= 1+ \sum_{j=1}^{k}(\sum_{m=2^{j-1}+1}^{2^j} \frac 1m)$$

The proof is much easier to read without all this sigma stuff.